# Variable expansion is not working as intended with curl

Tags: shell

I am having some trouble figuring out the expansion of a variable in my shell script. If I replace the variable with the desired string it works.

```
#!/bin/zsh

KEY="$(curl -Ivs -X GET "http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1" &> >(awk '/^> Authorization/{ print $3 " " $4 }'))" 
# The string returned by the curl and awk command is Basic "YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" without double quotes.

curl -H "Authorization: $KEY" "http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/WlanMacFilterRpm.htm?Page=1&exclusive=1" 
# This doesn't work

curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" "http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/WlanMacFilterRpm.htm?Page=1&exclusive=1" 
# This works
```

The only thing thats different in the above two lines is.

- `-H "Authorization: $KEY"`
- `-H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="`

Comment: Seems like `$KEY` is not set.  Did you echo `$KEY` after the assignment to see what it holds?

Comment: @codeforester Yes I did. adding `echo $KEY` just after getting the key, echoes `./filt.sh
Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
<!--Web Server Error Report:<HR>
<H1>Server Error: 401 N/A</H1>...`

Comment: Then, that's the problem, right?  Why do you need to send stderr of curl command to awk, through `&>`?

Comment: @codeforester Only stderr of curl contains my desired header so to get rid of stdout as well I pipe them both using `&>`, I then parse the output of curl (stdout and stderr) and print it appropriately. Which is then bound to KEY (I hope). I then need to make another curl request with that KEY as a part of a header.

Comment: I think I now understand what you mean. The output of echo is only `Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` . The remaining is from the lower curl command.

Comment: Run your script with `zsh -x yourscript`, and update your post with the output. This shows what the shell sees, while `echo` just shows what a human would see. Chances are there's a carriage return at the end of your variable.

Comment: @thatotherguy Whoa. You are right! Apparently "\C-M" has been added to the value of the key. `KEY=$'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=\C-M'
+filt.sh:5> echo $'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=\C-M'
Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
+filt.sh:7> curl -H $'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=\C-M' 'http:/` . I cannot remove it using tr it seems.

Comment: You can definitely remove it with `tr -d '\r'`. If you can't figure out where in your command expansion to put it, do it in a separate step.

Comment: @thatotherguy Hey it worked! I was trying `tr -d '\C-M'`. Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP generally uses DOS style CR+LF line terminators. Whenever you parse data out of `curl`, you have to account for this.

To check if this is the problem, run your script with `bash -x yourscript` or `zsh -x yourscript` to see trace output that shows otherwise invisible carriage returns:

```
var=$'value\C-M'   # zsh
var=$'value\r'     # bash
```

(Dash and ash/busybox unfortunately doesn't highlight this problem, so try with one of the above shells)

To strip them, pipe your data through `tr -d '\r'`.